# how to load my own .dll library generated by VS2010 in android project?

Tags: android, sphinx, speech-recognition

I am working on pocketsphinx android. I have generated a java wrapper for C, using swig tool in visual studio 2010. I replace the new java files and JNI file with the old ones in the folder. But I do not know where to place the new .dll library in the project, so that it can replace the old one "pocketsphinx_JNI".

Here is the code where it loads the library:

```
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("pocketsphinx_jni");
  }
```

P.S: I am working on android emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.  DLL's are a Windows library and Android runs on a Linux Kernel.  You need to use the Android NDK to build a compatible Shared Object (SO) file.

Comment: So you mean to say, i will have to generate libpocketsphinxjni.so and replace it with the current android project's shared object?

Comment: Yes.  There should be a lib folder and you need to add the SO file in there.

Comment: i am using swig to make .SO file, but it does not generate .o and .class files when i run this command : swig -java file.i, can you please tell me why is this so?